# How to compile avx assembly in Ubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: 14.04, g++

I'm trying to compile some avx instructions

```
{
        double* dst = NULL;
    const int* ait = a;
    int N=0;
    const int* aend = a+N;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "0:\n"
        "vmovupd (%1),%%xmm0\n"
        "vcvtdq2pd %%xmm0,%%ymm1\n"
        "vmovapd %%ymm1,(%0)\n"
        "addq $16,%1\n"
        "addq $32,%0\n"
        "cmpq %2,%1\n"
        "jb 0b\n"
        : "=r"(dst),"=r"(ait),"=r"(aend)
        : "0"(dst),"1"(ait),"2"(aend)
        : "%xmm0","%ymm1","memory"
        );
    }
```

and I get this error:

```
error: unknown register name ‘%ymm1’ in ‘asm’
```

Although I use flags `-mmmx` and `-msse2` as indicated in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333185/c-fix-unknown-register-name-xmm1-in-asm) it does not work for me.

What should I do?

Comment: Is it a typo ? '%%xmm0 %%ymm1' , two %% ?

Comment: No, it's not a typo. Here's the original code I try to build https://github.com/tfhe/tfhe/blob/master/src/libtfhe/fft_processors/spqlios/fft_processor_spqlios.cpp

Comment: That helps looking ....